# How to run a function in jQuery for 15 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function

```
 setInterval(function () {
        secondPlay()
    }, 1000);


    setInterval(function () {
        secondPlay1()
    }, 1000);
function secondPlay() {
    $("body").removeClass("play");

    var aa = $("ul.secondPlay li.active");
    var ii = $('ul.secondPlay li:last-child').val();
    if (aa.html() == undefined) {
        aa = $("ul.secondPlay li").eq(0);
        aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .next("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");

    }
    if (aa.is(":last-child")) {
        $("ul.secondPlay li").removeClass("before");
        aa.addClass("before").removeClass("active");
        aa = $("ul.secondPlay li").eq(0);
        aa.addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }
    else {
        $("ul.secondPlay li").removeClass("before");
           aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .next("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }

}
```

I want to run this function for `15 times`. How can I run it ?

Comment: Set a counter, increase it by 1 each time and only run the function if the counter is less than 15.

Comment: Do you mean you have to run this functions 15 times and then stop interval? Use a counter and increment it. When it reaches at 15, use `window.clearInterval()` to stop it.

Comment: use a while or a for loop

Comment: I am not getting where should I initialize the value if counter i

Comment: Do you want to run it after some seconds or immediately?

Comment: Please read [MCVE]. There is no need to include all the code of the function you are trying to run, as it is not relevant for the problem at hand. Please consider removing all unnecessary parts of your code to make the question clearer for future visitors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setInterval, you could use a timeout:

```
var i = 0;
function secondPlay1() {
// do function
 setTimeout(function() {
   if (i < 15) {
      i++;
      secondPlay1();
   }
 }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: @Rohitashv Singhal oh really?

Comment: So your setTimeout will execute and complete in one cycle. So now you will have to call it again. setInterval is ideally meant for looping with specific delay.

Comment: @Rajesh - yeah, you're right.  That was a mess. Never should have got the points.  I've fixed it up - but voted for your answer anyhow (even though I don't like intervals).  :)

Comment: @sideroxylon one issue in this solution is, if I call this function from outside, say a button click, setTimeout will be registered again. Although, nothing will happen, `i` is greater than 15, but still every time this function is called, setTimeout will be registered. Its like wasting resources.

Comment: @Rajesh - yes, that's possible, but I'd just re-set `i` in the click function.  Anyhow, your answer is probably better.

Comment: Consider a case where I want to run this function *15 times* on a event, but *only once* on other. Yes you can reset value of `i` when you want to rerun, but if you use recursion, you will have to code to handle special cases. Plus, you would be registering setTimeouts even when you don't need them to.

Comment: Also I'm not here to prove, my answer is better than anyone.

Answer (score 6):

Declare a variable as a counter. Increment that variable eachtime you calling the function. If the variable reaches 15, the stop the setInterval() by using clearInterval() function

```
var counter = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter == 15) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    secondPlay()
    counter++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why does interval need? it can be achieved without it. He just wants to run his code 15 times not on regular interval.

Comment: @Atul he is actually doing some ui changes, if you run it in a loop, the user wont see any changes on the ui. He should need some delay inbetwen

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code as reference.

```js
(function(){
  var count = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(count>15){
      window.crearInterval(interval);
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("lblCount").innerHTML = count;
      count++;
    }
  },1000);
})()
```

```html
<p id="lblCount"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
var timePlyed = 0;
function secondPlay() {
    timePlyed++;
    console.log(timePlyed);
    if (timePlyed != 15) {
        secondPlay();
    }
}
secondPlay();
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose them in a for loop?

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) { 
 ...
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to run it 15 times with delay (using `setInterval` function), so I'm not sure a for loop would help.

Comment: Oh. OP is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

you can use timeout function:

```
function secondPlay(i){
    console.log(i);
}

function test(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
       setTimeout(function(){
           secondPlay(i);
       }, i * 1000);
    }
}
```

call test() to execute the function.