# How to trigger a function on a button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I have created a function in jQuery as follow :

```
i = 0;
j = 0;

setInterval(function() {
if (i < 15) {
   secondPlay();
   i++;
}}, 1000);


setInterval(function() {
if (j < 15) {
   secondPlay1();
   j++;
}}, 1000);

function secondPlay() {
    $("body").removeClass("play");

    var aa = $("ul.secondPlay li.active");
    var ii = $('ul.secondPlay li:last-child').val();
    if (aa.html() == undefined) {
        aa = $("ul.secondPlay li").eq(0);
        aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .next("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");

    }
    if (aa.is(":last-child")) {
        $("ul.secondPlay li").removeClass("before");
        aa.addClass("before").removeClass("active");
        aa = $("ul.secondPlay li").eq(0);
        aa.addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }
    else {
        $("ul.secondPlay li").removeClass("before");
           aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .next("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }

}
function secondPlay1() {
    $("body").removeClass("play");
    var aa = $("ul.secondPlay1 li.active");

    if (aa.html() == undefined) {
        aa = $("ul.secondPlay1 li").eq(0);
        aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .next("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");

    }
    else if (aa.is(":last-child")) {
        $("ul.secondPlay1 li").removeClass("before");
        aa.addClass("before").removeClass("active");
        aa = $("ul.secondPlay1 li").eq(0);
        aa.addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }
    else {
        $("ul.secondPlay1 li").removeClass("before");
        aa.addClass("before")
            .removeClass("active")
            .next("li")
            .addClass("active")
            .closest("body")
            .addClass("play");
    }

}
```

HTML is as follow :

```
<ul class="flip secondPlay">
        <li class="">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">0</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">0</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="0">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="1">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">4</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="2">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="3">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">5</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">5</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="4">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">6</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="5">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">3</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="6">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">2</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="7">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">1</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="8">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">6</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="9">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">8</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">8</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="10">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">2</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="11">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">1</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="" value="12">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">9</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="before" value="13">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li class="active" value="14">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">7</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li value="15">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="up">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">8</div>
                </div>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <div class="inn">8</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
            </ul>
```

I have created a button with html as

```
<div class="buttons">
      <button id="trigger">Result!</button>
    </div>
```

On the click of the button `trigger` I want to call the functions `secondPlay` and `secondPlay1`.

How can I play this function on button click

and when

```
setInterval(function() {
if (i < 15) {
   secondPlay();
   i++;
}}, 1000);
```

function completes the 15 iterations, I want to show the value `2` in both the `divs` How can I achieve this

Comment: Can you share a  jsFiddle also?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#trigger', function(){ do stuff when clicked});` ?

Comment: The second part of the question **I want to show the value 2 in both the divs How can I achieve this ** is not clear.

Comment: i can see quite a complex `jquery` code above in your question above. So whats the big deal with button click?

Comment: what about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494113/how-to-run-a-function-in-jquery-for-15-times

Answer (score 0):

1. For calling `function` in `button`

   `<input id="trigger" type="button" value="Result!" onclick="secondPlay();" />`
2. On your function `secondPlay()`, add `secondPlay1` to call.